# A "link" that works on unwanted other lines of code

Tags: html, css, image, href

I have just started learning HTML and CSS code and have the following problem. I have a link to a site using an image. The link works fine, but it also works on other code on the next lines. (a heading and a paragraph) 
How can I prevent this?

```
<a href="photographicadventures.co.uk"<a/>;
<img src="images/w3schools.jpg" class="center" size width ="200" height="200">
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<h2>This is a Smaller Heading.</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph and is colored red and resized and centered due to the external style sheet </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to close the anchor tag  before your image  tag.  Think about wrapping the anchor tag AROUND the image tag.

Also the format of your closing tag wasn't correct. So the anchor remains open and includes the rest of your file.  You do not need the semicolon.

Here's the correct HTML:

```
<a href="photographicadventures.co.uk">
    <img src="images/w3schools.jpg" class="center" size width ="200" height="200">
</a>
<br><br><hr>
<h2>This is a Smaller Heading.</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph and is colored red and resized and centered due to the external style sheet</p>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I understand your code and can see where I went wrong.